# dash formatting x-axis of timeseries incorrectly

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am attempting to plot some timeseries data using plotly/Dash but the graph will not display correctly, despite the x-axis being of type 'datetime.date', 'datetime.datetime', or a correctly formatted string (nothing works...). What *could* be complicating matters is that I have generated the timeseries data using a different function, storing that into a dcc.Store object (as dict) and then converting that back into a Dataframe...but I have no idea for sure. My code is below, but to summarise the simple plan of action:

1. type Ticker of asset into Input box which generates a dict and stores into dcc.Store (I want to re-use this timeseries, hence storing it rather than repeating the external bloomberg call again and again)
2. immediately retrieve that dict from dcc.Store, convert back to a Dataframe and generate simple graph

When looking at the type of data generated at each step I can see that after I generate a dict using df.to_dict(), I have data of the type:

```
{'Date': {0: datetime.date(2017, 1, 1),
  1: datetime.date(2017, 2, 1),
  2: datetime.date(2017, 3, 1),
  3: datetime.date(2017, 4, 1),
.
.
 28: datetime.date(2019, 5, 1)},
 'FD004': {0: 18890.3544,
  1: 18296.9503,
  2: 18667.1757,
.
.
  28: 16697.2425}}
```

Then after the conversion of this dict back into a Dataframe I have:

```
          Date       FD004
0   2017-01-01  18890.3544
1   2017-02-01  18296.9503
2   2017-03-01  18667.1757
```

Where df['Date']:

```
0     2017-01-01
1     2017-02-01
2     2017-03-01
.
.
27    2019-04-01
28    2019-05-01
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

But I then convert that using to_datetime or astype('datetime64[ns]') which gives me the 'correct' dtype:

```
0    2017-01-01
1    2017-02-01
2    2017-03-01
.
.
27   2019-04-01
28   2019-05-01
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Indeed, when checking the final fig that is produced, I see that plotly has recognised it as a datetime object:

```
<bound method BaseFigure.show of Figure({
    'data': [{'type': 'scatter',
              'x': array([datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0),
                          datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 1, 0, 0),
                          datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 1, 0, 0),
                          . . . 
                          datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 1, 0, 0),
                          datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 1, 0, 0),
                          datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 1, 0, 0)], dtype=object),
              'y': array([18890.3544, 18296.9503, 18667.1757, ...
                          13202.488 , 14463.2424, 15025.5053, 16697.2425])}],
    'layout': {'template': '...'}
})>
```

But still...the graph displays like spaghetti:

[image]

***** EDIT / UPDATE *****

When I do not store the original Dataframe to_dict, the plot is perfect, so it appears as though something about the conversion from Dataframe to dict and back again (although all objects *appear* to have the correct datatype) is indeed what is causing the Date column to be interpreted incorrectly. So something fundamentally wrong with the to_dict() function or how plotly interprets this converted/reverted data?

My code:

```
app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
        html.Div(dcc.Input(id='fundTicker', type='text', 
                     debounce=True, placeholder='fundTicker'),
                style={'width':'100%'}), 

        html.Div(dcc.Graph(id='fundGraph'),  
                style={'width':'75%'}),

        dcc.Store(id='fundData'),
        ]
    )

@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='fundData', component_property='data'),
    [Input(component_id='fundTicker', component_property='value')]
    )

def returnFundData(fundTicker):
    fundData = bbg.bbgHistorical(fundTicker, '20170101', '20190501', 'MONTHLY', 'FD004')
    return fundData

@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='fundGraph', component_property='figure'),
    [Input(component_id='fundData', component_property='data')]
    )

def createFundGraph(fundData):

    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(fundData)
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
    fig = go.Figure()

    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['Date'], y=df['FD004']))

    return fig    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the dates are not all sorted by increasing order, hence the "spaghetti" look (when going back in time). The data displayed by your prints look sorted so I'm not sure but the central part is missing, to check whether they are sorted run

```
np.all(np.sort(df['Date']) == df['Date'])
```

You could either sort your data (eg using `np.sort` and `np.argsort`) or if you're happy with points only and not lines, use `mode='markers'` for the scatter plot (cf https://plot.ly/python/line-and-scatter/).

Comment: Thank you very much, from previous searches I was sent down the 'object has become incorrect type route'...which was obviously a red herring. What is completely mad is that the test you suggest above returns True, but after running an extra line (    df = df.sort_values(by='Date')) and plotting the graph, everything is displaying correctly. Some pretty weird behaviour... but thank you nonetheless for pointing me in (obvious!) direction.